# Added columns to SQLiteDatabase, can no longer read from it

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, cursor

My SQLiteDatabase was working fine with just 3 entries, the UUID, Title and Date, but ever since I added some more columns I am getting this error.

Not sure what it can be, I have read that 0,-1 means that the column cannot be read, but I have made sure to spell all my column names correctly.

## CrimeCursorWrapper.java

```
public List<Crime> getCrimes() {
        List<Crime> crimes = new ArrayList<>();
        CrimeCursorWrapper cursor = queryCrimes(null, null);
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                crimes.add(cursor.getCrime());
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } finally{
            cursor.close();
        }
        return crimes;
    }
```

## CrimeLab.java:

```
public Crime getCrime(UUID id) {
        CrimeCursorWrapper cursor = queryCrimes(
                CrimeTable.Cols.UUID + " = ?",
                new String[] { id.toString() }
        );
        try {
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getCrime();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

private static ContentValues getContentValues(Crime crime) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CrimeTable.Cols.UUID, crime.getId().toString());
        values.put(CrimeTable.Cols.TITLE, crime.getTitle());
        values.put(CrimeTable.Cols.DATE, crime.getDate().getTime());
        values.put(CrimeTable.Cols.ACTTYPE, crime.getActType().toString());
        values.put(CrimeTable.Cols.PLACE, crime.getPlace().toString());
        values.put(CrimeTable.Cols.DURATION, crime.getDuration().toString());
        values.put(CrimeTable.Cols.COMMENT, crime.getComment().toString());
        return values;
    }

    private CrimeCursorWrapper queryCrimes(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
                CrimeTable.NAME,
                null, // Columns - null selects all columns
                whereClause,
                whereArgs,
                null, // groupBy
                null, // having
                null // orderBy
        );
        return new CrimeCursorWrapper(cursor);
    }
```

## CrimeCursorWrapper.java:

```
public class CrimeCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper{

    public CrimeCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public Crime getCrime() {
        String uuidString = getString(getColumnIndex(CrimeTable.Cols.UUID));
        String title = getString(getColumnIndex(CrimeTable.Cols.TITLE));
        long date = getLong(getColumnIndex(CrimeTable.Cols.DATE));
        String actType = getString(getColumnIndex(CrimeTable.Cols.ACTTYPE));
        String place = getString(getColumnIndex(CrimeTable.Cols.PLACE));
        String duration = getString(getColumnIndex(CrimeTable.Cols.DURATION));
        String comment = getString(getColumnIndex(CrimeTable.Cols.COMMENT));


        Crime crime = new Crime(UUID.fromString(uuidString));

        crime.setTitle(title);
        crime.setDate(new Date(date));
        crime.setActType(actType);
        crime.setPlace(place);
        crime.setDuration(duration);
        crime.setComment(comment);

        return crime;
    }

}
```

## Crime.java:

```
public class Crime {

    private UUID mId;
    private String mTitle;
    private Date mDate;
    private String mActType;
    private String mPlace;
    private String mDuration;
    private String mComment;


    public Crime() {
        this(UUID.randomUUID());
    }

    public Crime(UUID id) {
        mId = id;
        mDate = new Date();
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return mId;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        mDate = date;
    }
    public String getPhotoFilename() {
        return "IMG_" + getId().toString() + ".jpg";
    }
    public String getActType() {
        return mActType;
    }
    public void setActType(String actType) {
        mActType = actType;
    }
    public String getPlace() {
        return mPlace;
    }
    public void setPlace(String place) {
        mPlace = place;
    }
    public String getDuration() {
        return mDuration;
    }
    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        mDuration = duration;
    }
    public String getComment() {
        return mComment;
    }
    public void setComment(String comment) {
        mComment = comment;
    }

}
```

Comment: `I am getting this error` What error? Can you post the error?

Answer (score 0):

It "CAN" be the reason: If you use your physical mobile device for debugging, after you change your database tables inside the code, delete your application's data from the mobile device and reinstall your apk (or press debug or run buttons). Database files are not updating automatically by Android Studio.

Comment: I use an emulator to test the app, and I did uninstall the app from the menu, still having the same issues.

Comment: Ok let's try this, do not uninstall the app but go to settings>application settings>your application>Storage>Clear Data

Answer (score 0):

Did you change version of your database after adding more columns? It is mandatory.